# How can I reverse an animation in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit, reverse

I'm learning how to use the animation functions in `SceneKit` using the Fox 2 example (you can find it here https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/604/ and here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/scenekit-2017/Introduction/Intro.html) and I have a question:

How can I reverse an animation?

I searched in the official documentation (that is very very poor) and online but it seems that there isn't a built-in function that can reverse an animation.

I found three interesting parameters:

- `.autoreverses`: "when true, the object plays backwards after playing forwards. Defaults to NO"
- `.fillsBackward`: "when true, the animation is active before its active duration and evaluates to its start value. Defaults to NO"
- `.fillsForward`: "when true, the animation remains active after its active duration and evaluates to its end value. Defaults to NO"

The problem is that the first parameter doesn't do what I want and when I use the other two parameters, nothing happens: S

This is how I use these parameters:

- Where I load the animation in the character model

  ```
  let spinAnimation = Character.loadAnimation(fromSceneNamed: "Art.scnassets/character/max_spin.scn")
  spinAnimation.animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
  spinAnimation.speed = 1.5
  spinAnimation.stop()
  model!.addAnimationPlayer(spinAnimation, forKey: "spin")
  ```
- Where I create the character and start the animation

  ```
  character2 = Character.init(scene: scnScene!)
  character2?.model.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.15, y: -0.3, z: 0)
  scnScene!.rootNode.addChildNode(character2!.node!)
  character2?.model.animationPlayer(forKey: "spin")?.animation.fillsForward = true //or fillsBackward or autoreverses
  character2?.model.animationPlayer(forKey: "spin")?.play()
  ```

Did I misunderstand `.fillsBackward` and `.fillsForward`? Is there an exhaustive and updated documentation of SceneKit?

Comment: Please post the code that you're having a problem with.  We can't help you debug something if we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: "Is there an exhaustive and updated documentation of SceneKit?", no. Unfortunately. Try making the animation speed a negative number.

Comment: It works! So...what's the meaning of fillsBackward and fillsForward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to close this question since the problem is solved so:
To reverse an animation in SceneKit, simply set the speed to a negative value (ex: -1)

Comment: Works flawlessly. Apple could have really mentioned that in a short sentence.

Comment: I was searching for this solution an I thought the same but I did not dare to try it, thanx to you, it works like magic :)